Example of a premonoidal category for the purpose of understanding why separate functoriality does not imply joint functoriality
I'm reading Bartosz Milewski's Category Theory for Programmers, where in §8.1 Bifunctors, it is written that

in general, separate functoriality is not enough to prove joint functoriality. Categories in which joint functoriality fails are called premonoidal.

but, at least in that chapter, nothing else is said about this topic.
So I've opened Categories for the Working Mathematician from Saunders Mac Lane, and at page 37 I found Proposition 1, which relates functors and bifunctors, by stating what is the condition under which the existence of two functors $L_c : B \to D$ and $M_b : C \to D$ implies the existence of a bifunctor $S : B \times C \to D$.
I'm surely having a hard time understanding the proof, but I'm having a hard time imagining an example of a premonoidal category, so one where joint functoriality is absent, even if separate functoriality does exist.
I'm found this other question, where the OP claims to have found an example themselves, and writes about it in the question itself; however, I really have little confidence in confirming or rejecting that explanation, especially because I'm puzzled by one bit of it: when I read

$$
F(g,h)=
\begin{cases}
1_a,&g=h=f,\\
1_b,&\text{otherwise},
\end{cases}
$$

I would deduce that $F(1_b, 1_b) = 1_a$, but the following part of the explanation claims that $F(1_b, 1_b) = 1_b$.

I suppose I could start from that example of the category $C$ with 3 morphisms $1_a$, $1_b$, and $a \to b$ (the one in the referenced question), consider $C \times C$,
$\require{AMScd}$
$$
\begin{CD}
(a,b) @>{(f,1_b)}>> (b,b) \\ 
@A{(1_a,f)}AA @AA{(1_b, f)}A \\ 
(a,a) @>>{(f,1_a)}> (b,a)
\end{CD}
$$
and verify that I can indeed define a "non-functor" from this category to another category $D$ by using two actual functors $C \to D$.

In answering this question, please, take into account that I'm not a mathematician.

A quick web search for "premonoidal category examples" brings up nLab, which gives the example of the Kleisli category of a non-commutative strong monad on a monoidal category. Intuitively, this is clear: you can't effectfully map both components of a tuple at once without picking an order to sequence effects in.
